# com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (77 > -1)

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

I recently encountered a problem，mysql-connector throws a Exception, it means max_allowed_packet=-1 ,but when i query my database,it show as follows:
max_allowed_packet = 67108864

the error detail as follows:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: **Packet for query is too large (77 > -1).** You can change this value on the
>   server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.**readPacket(MysqlIO.java:612)**
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:415)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2581)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1757)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2171)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1364)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:56)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:70)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:57)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:259)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:132)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_43]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_43]    at
>   org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:46)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   com.baidu.bainuo.bppoi.interceptor.MybatisInterceptor.intercept(MybatisInterceptor.java:67)
>   ~[bp-poi-service-1.0.20-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:57)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.query(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:98)
>   ~[mybatis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor161.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_43]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_43]    at
>   org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:358)
>   ~[mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]     ... 54 common frames omitted

Comment: increase the value of max_allowed_packet in your jdbc url you can give at the end

Comment: When I restart the program, this error does not appear 。 when reviewing jdbc code  ,i find in ConnectioinPropertiesImpl.java  ,  set  max_allowed_packet  default =-1  ;but when create a connection , the max_allowed_packet will reset value to the variable max_allowed_packet in mysql server

Comment: if you're sure you increased it then you still need to restart the mysql server after that

Comment: I think mysql server is ok , when restart my program , the error does not apper.  Why should there be -1。  In msql server .the max_allowed_packet is set 10 *1024*1024 .

Answer (score 0):

Consider correcting your jdbc code to match your requirements.
MySQL 5.6 server variables indicates the minimum value is 1024.